# VBA Application.Evaluate() with parameter values from "1" to "4"

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this test code below:

```
Public Sub runTest()

    Dim result As String
    
    result = Application.Evaluate("4")
    MsgBox "ss"
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to add numbers 1,2,3,4 as parameter to Application.Evaluate it fails with the following error:

[image]

I have the following Excel version:
Microsoft® Excel® a Microsoft 365 MSO (2206 build version 16.0.15330.20260) 64 bit

What I could catch one thing more: if I seckthe runtime object of Application.Evaluate("4") it returns an  OLE object(?) but Application.Evaluate("5") as Double.

[image]

Why? What's the point here?

--- UPDATE ---

I add this picture as well to see all the information I know of this thing:

[image]

Comment: What are your expectation regarding `Application.Evaluate("4")`? Do you expect to convert the string in a numeric value? `Evaluate` does not do that... For such a conversion try `CLng("4")`, IDbl("4"), CInt("4"), according to the value you try converting. Of course, you previously should check if `IsNumeric("4")`. And instead of "4", of course you try using a `String` variable having a value looking as numeric...

Comment: Okay, so I don't mean to convert this and my question isn't connect to casting I want to know why Application.Evaluate() returns differently if the parameter is numerical.

Comment: For me, `? Typename(Application.Evaluate("4"))` in the Immediate Window returns `Double`.

Comment: I still cannot get you, I am afraid... If you declare a variable `As String` and then use `Evaluate(3)`, it evaluates as string. And viceversa...

Comment: Try `Dim result As String, x As Long`, then `x = Evaluate("4")` followed by `Debug.Print TypeName(x), x`. `result = Evaluate(4)` followed by `Debug.Print TypeName(result), result`. Excel evaluates to match the declared variable type...

Comment: Please check my images again. When I run Application.Evaluate("5") it returns a Double 
 type (check the watch window), but if I run Application.Evaluate("4") it return an OLEObject. This is my question: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate), the purpose of `Application.Evaluate` is to *convert a Microsoft Excel name to an object or a value*, not anything else. This comes with its rules, one of which is:

> The following types of names in Microsoft Excel can be used with this method:
>
> - ...
> - **Form Control number.** You can specify a number, as well as a name, to refer to Form Control on a worksheet. For example, for Label located on a worksheet (Developer tab - Insert - Form Controls - Label), both `Evaluate("Label 1").Caption = "Hello"` and `Evaluate("1").Caption = "Hello"` do the same.

You must have four Form controls on that worksheet, so `Evaluate("1")` - `Evaluate("4")` return them. `Evaluate("5")` doesn't, because you don't have a fifth Form control.

Comment: This is the correct answer! I have 4 buttons on my sheet. When I added a fifth one I couldn't run the Evaluate("5") "properly". Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to let users input simple math expressions as quantities. They could enter .5 + .5 and it would evaluate as 1. But if they entered 1 it would fail because the 1 was being interpreted as a button on the sheet.

I came up with this workaround:

```
Dim userQuant As Variant
userQuant = InputBox("Please enter the needed quantity.", "Quantity")
userQuant = Application.Evaluate("0 + " & userQuant)
```